# Assignment in an expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to make a directive which receives expression as a callback to bootstrap's 'hidden.bs.modal' event:

```
//the use
<div class="modal" modal-on-hide="currPane = 'firstPanel'">

//the implementation
app.directive('modalOnHide', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('hidden.bs.modal', function hideCallback () {
        scope.$eval(attrs.modalOnHide);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

currPane is an attr on the parent scope which is the same scope as the directive's, yet, when hideCallback executes, it's not being set to the new value. Idea?

Comment: what is the result of doing a  console.log(scope.currPane) inside your handler right before you do the eval and right after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
element.on('hidden.bs.modal', function hideCallback () {
    scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.$eval(attrs.modalOnHide);
    });
});
```

Or:

```
element.on('hidden.bs.modal', function hideCallback () {
    scope.$apply(attrs.modalOnHide);
});
```

Comment: Yap, that easy. Your beer is on me.  (They both work)

Comment: @Birowsky Distance is problem, not beer :D